# Java 7, try-with-resources: can i omit creating Connection and PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, try-catch, java-7, autocloseable

Case A:

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionURL);
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table"); 
     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

     processResults(rs);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Case B:

```
try (ResultSet rs = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionURL)
                                 .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table")
                                 .executeQuery()) {
     processResults(rs);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the **case A** `con`, `ps` and `rs` will be closed automatically. What about **case B**? In the **case B** the variables `con` and `ps` don't create as it was in **case A**.

*My question:* are the both cases completely identical? Is there any problems in **case B**?

Comment: What is your question? A try-with-resources will close the resource, that's what it's for. But `Connection.prepateStatement` returns a `PreparedStatement`, not a `ResultSet`, so your code doesn't compile.

Comment: I've updated my question. What about PreparedStatement now? Case B is correct?

Comment: Case B is not correct, because neither the `Connection` nor the `PreparedStatement` can ever get closed. Only the items which are *declared* in the try block are auto-closed.

Comment: @EJP **Thanks!** That's what I wanted to hear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case B is not correct, because neither the `Connection` nor the `PreparedStatement` can ever get closed. Only the items which are *declared* in the `try` block are auto-closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are using try with resource (using JDK 7 or above) so your prepared statement would be closed automatically. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) page for your reference. PreparedStatement/Connection does implement AutoCloseable interface internally which makes perfect sense to use it with try with resource block.

You could try something like:

```
public void doDbOperation(int id) {
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionURL);
     PreparedStatement ps = createStatement(con, userId); 
     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {//auto close

     processResults(rs);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return users;
}

private PreparedStatement createStatement(Connection con, int id) throws SQLException {
     String sql = "SELECT myid FROM table WHERE id = ?";
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     ps.setInt(1, id);
    return ps;
}

private void processResults(ResultSet rs) { 
   // business logic
}
```